# How to integrate Windows Mobile SDK help into VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

(excuse me for my bad english)

I have installed 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Pro' and its 'MSDN Library' (SP1).
Next, i'v installed 'Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK Refresh'.
'Platform SDK' or 'Windows SDK' is not installed.

Question: how to integrate WM6 SDK help into the VS help system?

That is, for example, i am in VS editor window with WM6 C++ project. Cursor is over API-function 'CreateWindow'. When i press F1 - help is loaded on 'CreateWindow' function for '**big-PC**' WinAPI. But i need help on this function for **mobile** WinAPI. Or at least i'd like to see several options to choose - from which SDK to show info on this function.
Previously, when i had VS 2005 and installed the same WM6 SDK (mentioned above), everything worked as it should.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution here (thanks to ondrej_bohaciak):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/windowsmobiledev/thread/8CCF923F-05DA-46B4-8ECB-83DD2851A118

File InnovaHxReg.exe you can get installing Innovasys HelpStudio Lite:
innovasys.com_products_hslite_overview.aspx
(replace '_' with '/')